# this block of code going straight to break in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have this block in a switch case statement that when selected, just breaks and presents me with the main menu again.

```
 System.out.println("Choose a competitor surname");
    String competitorChoice2 = input.nextLine();
    int lowestSpeed = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int highestSpeed = 0;

    for(int j = 0; j < clipArray.length; j++) {

        if(clipArray[j] != null) {
            if(competitorChoice2.equals(clipArray[j].getSurname())) {
                if(clipArray[j].getSpeed() > clipArray[highestSpeed].getSpeed()) {
                    highestSpeed = j;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < clipArray.length; i++) {

        if(clipArray[i] != null) {
            if(competitorChoice2.equals(clipArray[i].getSurname())) {
                if(clipArray[i].getSpeed() < clipArray[lowestSpeed].getSpeed()) {
                    lowestSpeed = i;
                }
            }
        }
   }  

   for(int h = lowestSpeed; h < highestSpeed; h++ ) {

       System.out.println(""+clipArray[h].getLength());
   }
```

I have an array of objects and each object has a surname and a speed.

I want the user to choose a surname and display the speeds of all of their clips from lowest to highest.

when I select this option it just breaks and brings me back to the main menu

The speeds are also originally entered as floats.

here is the menu:

```
while (true) {
        System.out.println("Please select one of the following options by entering a number: \n"
                + "1) Quit\n"
                + "2) Add a new clip to the records\n"
                + "3) View information about a clip via an index number\n"
                + "4) Change information about a clip via an index number\n"
                + "5) List all competitors which have a clip recorded\n"
                + "6) Choose a competitor and display their longest clip\n"
                + "7) Choose a competitor and display their clips arranged by speed\n"
                + "8) display elements of array in alphabetical order");

        choice = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        switch (choice) {

switch (choice) {
            case (1):
                System.out.println("You have quit the program");
                System.exit(0);
            case (2):
                    Clip c = new Clip();

                    System.out.println("Set an index number between 1-1000");
                    int setIndexNumber = input.nextInt();
                    c.setIndexNumber(setIndexNumber);

                    System.out.println("What is the given name of the competitor?");
                    String givenName = input.next();
                    c.setGivenName(givenName);

                    System.out.println("What is the surname of the competitor?");
                    String surname = input.next();
                    c.setSurname(surname);

                    System.out.println("What is the length of the clip?");
                    float setLength = input.nextFloat();
                    c.setLength(setLength);

                    System.out.println("What is the speed of the competitor?");
                    float setSpeed = input.nextFloat();
                    c.setSpeed(setSpeed);

                    System.out.println("What what time was this recorded? (24 hour)");
                    System.out.println("Enter hour: ");
                    int setHour = input.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter minute: ");
                    int setMin = input.nextInt();
                    c.setTime(setHour, setMin);

                    clipArray[firstAvailableIndex()] = c;
                    counter++;
                break;
            case (3):
                System.out.println("Which clip do you want to view?\n"
                        + "Select from index 0-1000:");
                int indexNo = input.nextInt();

                for (int j = 0; j < clipArray.length; j++) {
                    if (j == indexNo) {
                        System.out.println("Index Number: " + clipArray[j].getIndexNumber());
                        System.out.println("Given Name: " + clipArray[j].getGivenName());
                        System.out.println("Surname: " + clipArray[j].getSurname());
                        System.out.println("Length: " + clipArray[j].getLength());
                        System.out.println("Speed: " + clipArray[j].getSpeed());
                        System.out.println("Time: " + clipArray[j].getHour() + ":" + clipArray[j].getMinute());
                        break;
                    }
                }



                break;
            case (4):
                System.out.println("Which clip do you want to change? choose and index number: ");
                int clipIndex = input.nextInt();
                input.nextLine();

                System.out.println("What do want to set this given name to?");
                String editGivenName = input.nextLine();
                clipArray[clipIndex].setGivenName(editGivenName);

                System.out.println("What do you want to set this surname to?");
                String editSurname = input.nextLine();
                clipArray[clipIndex].setSurname(editSurname);

                System.out.println("What do you want to set this length to?");
                float editLength = input.nextFloat();
                clipArray[clipIndex].setLength(editLength);

                System.out.println("What do you want to set this speed to?");
                float editSpeed = input.nextFloat();
                clipArray[clipIndex].setSpeed(editSpeed);

                System.out.println("What do you want to set this hour to?");
                int editHour = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("What do you want to set this minute to?");
                int editMin = input.nextInt();
                clipArray[clipIndex].setTime(editHour, editMin);


                break;
            case (5):
                for (int g = 0; g < clipArray.length; g++) {

                    if (clipArray[g] != null) {
                        System.out.println(""+clipArray[g].getSurname());
                    }

                }


                break;
            case (6):
                System.out.println("Choose a competitor by surname");
                String competitorChoice = input.nextLine();
                int longestClip = 0;

                for(int i = 0; i < clipArray.length; i++) {

                    if(clipArray[i] != null) {
                        if (competitorChoice.equals(clipArray[i].getSurname())) {

                            if(clipArray[i].getLength() > clipArray[longestClip].getLength()) {
                                longestClip = i;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }


                System.out.println(""+clipArray[longestClip].getLength()+", at Index: "+clipArray[longestClip].getIndexNumber());

                break;
            case (7):
                    System.out.println("Choose a competitor surname");
                    String competitorChoice2 = input.nextLine();
                    int lowestSpeed = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                    int highestSpeed = 0;

                    for(int j = 0; j < clipArray.length; j++) {

                        if(clipArray[j] != null) {
                            if(competitorChoice2.equals(clipArray[j].getSurname())) {
                                if(clipArray[j].getSpeed() > clipArray[highestSpeed].getSpeed()) {
                                    highestSpeed = j;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                     }

                    for(int i = 0; i < clipArray.length; i++) {

                        if(clipArray[i] != null) {
                            if(competitorChoice2.equals(clipArray[i].getSurname())) {
                                if(clipArray[i].getSpeed() < clipArray[lowestSpeed].getSpeed()) {
                                    lowestSpeed = i;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                     }





                    for(int h = lowestSpeed; h < highestSpeed; h++ ) {
                        System.out.println(""+clipArray[h].getLength());
                    }

                break;
            case (8):
                   for(int i = 1; i < counter; i++) {
                       for(int j = 0; j < counter - 1; j++) {
                           if(((clipArray[j].getSurname()).compareToIgnoreCase((clipArray[j+1].getSurname()))) > 0) {
                               Clip temp = clipArray[j];
                               clipArray[j] = clipArray[j+1];
                               clipArray[j+1] = temp;
                           }
                       }
                   }
                   for(int g = 0; g < counter; g++) {
                       System.out.println(clipArray[g].getSurname());
                   }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("you have not selected a valid option");
                break;
        }//end of switch case
```

EDIT: out of bounds exceptions at the if statement for the lowest speed

Comment: Post the code of the switch and/or menu.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that `clipArray` has elements that are not `null`?

Comment: Seems like @PM77-1 is asking a fair question. Also take a look at your lowestSpeed and highestSpeed declarations. With these two things in mind, it is very possible this switch case might not do anything.

Comment: Yes it is an array of 1000 elements and it creates them as I enter them which is an option in the switch case which I just posted. It just breaks though at this point

Comment: what is the problem with the declarations?

Comment: You didn't post the relevant part yet. Can we have the **entire** `switch` block?

Comment: Well the thing is that your loops only do something if the array elements are not null. Your third loop will also never run because you've declared lowestSpeed to be > highestSpeed. Your speed variables will never change if the array elements are null. Although assuming the very first line is inside the switch case, "Choose a competitor surname" will print.

Comment: @PM77-1 ok i'll post the entire switch block, i also updated to show what exception I am getting now

Comment: @user2914851 So, it's not actually `break;`ing. It's an exception. If you'd posted the complete exception at the beginning it would have been completely obvious what the problem was, as it is now. Exceptions are there to help you. They contain incredibly important information, that if you read it, details the meaning and location of problem. Don't just ignore them and complain that it "breaks".

Comment: it was breaking before and going back to the menu then i added some coded and deleted it and returned to normal and now its throwing an exception that it wasn't before

Comment: What is the index it tells you when you get the exception? It will say something like ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (4). Though I suspect the index number == Integer.MAX_VALUE since that's what lowestSpeed is initialized to.

Comment: Post the **entire** exception text, including stack trace.  Why do we have to pull information bit by bit?

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException  2147483647

Comment: Yes, that's your first problem. What size are you initializing clipArray to? I hope you aren't initializing it to Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When lowestSpeed is Integer.MAX_VALUE, that's out of bounds for the clipArray. Change the initialization for lowestSpeed to:

```
int lowestSpeed = 0;
```

Initializing a variable to the maximum before doing a loop that searches for the minimum is appropriate when the variable is used to store the minimum value itself, but in this case it's not: it's storing the index of the element having the minimum value, so start with the first valid index (*Er, I think*).

Comment: Yes but looking at the logic I suspect that is not the only problem.